# C&CP-Symmetry Violation in Baryogenesis

Tags: big-bang, antimatter, matter, baryogenesis

In cosmology, during the big bang; how does C-Symmetry violation allow for a greater number of baryons to be produced than anti-baryons in Baryogenesis, similarly how does CP-Symmetry tie into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ stands for *charge*. 
*Charge* symmetry implies that if the charge of all particles were to be inverted  - particles become anti-particles and viceversa - the universe would look exactly the same. A universe made of matter would be indistinguishable from one made of antimatter.

So if a given process allows for two matter particles (say, a proton and a neutron) to bind together (into deuteron$^*$), the same process should be happening for their antimatter counterparts (antiproton and antineutron into antideuteron). Hence, we would end up with deuteron and antideuteron in the same universe, which means that at some point they are likely to come into contact. And what happens when you have matter and antimatter in contact with one another? They blow up via annihilation. And goodbye baryons.

In order to have a stable, long-living population of baryons, therefore, you need certain mechanisms to favour *matter* over antimatter. If you end up with, say, $N+1$ deuterons and $N$ antideuterons, only $N$ pairs annihilate and you are left with one deuteron. If they favour matter over antimatter it means that they are discriminating against *charge*, i.e. charge symmetry is being broken.

This, in short, is the first [Sakharov condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#Sakharov_conditions), although usually states in terms of Baryon number conservation.

$CP$ violation is slightly more complicated. Suffice to say that breaking $CP$ symmetry allows, again, to distinguish between matter and antimatter and to therefore favour the fomer over the latter.

[*] A deuteron is just the nucleus of a Deuterium atom, i.e. a neutron and a proton bound together.